ros2 controller manager does not spawn move group
I am using a real UR10e and controlling it with ros2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04. What I am trying is to define the planning_pipelines as is done in this ompl_constrained_planning tutorial. My current directory structure is like this:
ros2_ws/src/
 custom_ur_moveit_config/  
  config/
   controllers.yaml
   kinematics.yaml etc.
   ur10e_robot.srdf 
   ur10e_robot.urdf.xacro
  launch/
   ompl_constrained_path_launch.py
  src/
   ompl_constrained_path_launch.cpp
  urdf/
   ur10e.urdf

I usually launch my ur_control_launch.py first, then the ur_moveit_launch.py ur_type:=ur10e and then I try to launch the ompl_constrained_path_launch.py below. This is how I am defining my moveit_config in my launch file right now and try to load the controllers:
moveit_config = (
        MoveItConfigsBuilder("custom_ur_moveit_config")
        .robot_description(file_path="config/ur10e_robot.urdf.xacro")
        .robot_description_semantic(file_path="config/ur10e_robot.srdf")
        .robot_description_kinematics(file_path="config/kinematics.yaml")
        .joint_limits(file_path="config/joint_limits.yaml")
        .trajectory_execution(file_path="config/controllers.yaml")
        .planning_pipelines(pipelines=["ompl"])
        .to_moveit_configs()
    )
    
    # Set planning pipeline parameters
    moveit_config.planning_pipelines["ompl"]["ur_manipulator"][
        "enforce_constrained_state_space"
    ] = True
    moveit_config.planning_pipelines["ompl"]["ur_manipulator"][
        "projection_evaluator"
    ] = "joints(shoulder_pan_joint,shoulder_lift_joint)"
ros2_controllers_path = os.path.join(
        get_package_share_directory("custom_ur_moveit_config"),
        "config",
        "ros2_controllers.yaml",
    )
    # maybe provide absolute path ^^
    ros2_control_node = Node(
        package="controller_manager",
        executable="ros2_control_node",
        parameters=[ros2_controllers_path],
        remappings=[
            ("/controller_manager/robot_description", "/robot_description"),
        ],
        output="both",
    )

    # Load controllers
    load_controllers = []
    for controller in [
        "ur_manipulator",
    ]:
        load_controllers += [
            ExecuteProcess(
                cmd=["ros2 run controller_manager spawner {}".format(controller)],
                shell=True,
                output="screen",
            )
        ]

The error messages include this:
[ros2_control_node-5] [INFO] [1719221933.896421916] [controller_manager]: Received robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-5] [WARN] [1719221933.896438487] [controller_manager]: ResourceManager has already loaded an urdf file. Ignoring attempt to reload a robot description file.
[ros2_control_node-5] [ERROR] [1719221935.014967271] [controller_manager]: The 'type' param was not defined for 'ur_manipulator'.
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner ur_manipulator-6] [FATAL] [1719221935.015929670] [spawner_ur_manipulator]: Failed loading controller ur_manipulator
[ros2 run controller_manager spawner ur_manipulator-6] [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 1
[ERROR] [ros2 run controller_manager spawner ur_manipulator-6]: process has died [pid 19312, exit code 1, cmd 'ros2 run controller_manager spawner ur_manipulator'].

I am not sure where I can define the type param for the ur_manipulator and how to make sure that the controller manager is able to spawn the control group that I defined 'ur_manipulator'. The ur_moveit_launch terminal window also reads this:
[rviz2-2] [WARN] [1719279171.646079673] [moveit_planning_scene.planning_scene]: Setting the scene for model 'ur10e_robot' but model 'ur' is loaded.

